# Tensorflow for GPU without Conda not working

Tags: tensorflow

I wanted to use tensorflow for GPU for my current project so I followed a tutorial from youtube to install it without using conda (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Q6SM_usn84)
I followed the tutorial and turns out there is no CUDA 11.2 for windows 11. Hence I installed the latest version i.e. CUDA 12 and followed the rest of the tutorial.

I then proceeded to create a virtualenv using python 3.10.10 and installed tensorflow using:
`pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.11.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` 
It did install successfully and imports but does not list my GPU as a physical device available.

After a bit of research I came across this "https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-do-i-install-cuda-11-0-on-windows-11-not-wsl2-windows-itself/192251" and reinstalled CUDA 11.2 for windows 10 in my windows 11 machine. Everything is still the same.
It imports but does not list my GPU as a physical device available.

Comment: you installed the CPU-only version of TF: `...windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu...`

Comment: For Windows, since version 2.11, there is only CPU versions of TensorFlow, to use GPU from 2.11 you have to use WSL, this is very clear in the website: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 1):

> "TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally,
> try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin"

Please install TensorFlow 2.10 and follow the **Step-by-step instructions** mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) to install TensorFlow with GPU support. Make sure all the **Hardware and Software requirements** are met as given in the link.

You need to install `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1` for tensorflow 2.10 to enable the GPU support as per the [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).